# `git lfs prune` is not pruning all lfs objects

Tags: git, storage, git-lfs, resource-cleanup

When I run `git lfs prune --dry-run --force` I got this:

```
prune: 1 local object, 0 retained, done.
prune: 1 file would be pruned (23 MB), done.
```

I know that one object, and I want to keep it. It is only 23M But my `.git/lfs/` folder is 176M. How is this possible? How to prune everything except that one file?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question: the output you show indicates that `git lfs prune` thinks the _only_ file that can safely be deleted is that 23MB file, and implicitly says that all of the other ones should be kept, yet you seem to want to do the opposite (keep that one file, delete all of the other ones). Perhaps you have another goal in mind ?

Comment: `--force` will try to prune many things but will still keep unpushed objects, perhaps that's the point you want to check ? check if, for all of your local, unpushed refs, either something needs to be pushed upstream, or your local changes need to be discarded ? ("local refs" includes the commits in your stash too)

Comment: @LeGEC `--force` might think it can safely delete only one file. But shouldn't it mention there a 'n' local objects? Or is there a better way to see how many local objects are there? And perhaps, which actual file they belong to?

Comment: rewording the question in my first comment: what is your intention ? do you want to delete local blobs because you know for a fact they aren't useful ?

Comment: @LeGEC No problem in deleting all other blobs than that one as I haven't committed anything myself and I had just fetched the repo. Mainly I want to know what it is storing in that 176M. If it is possible to know which file it is pointing to I would be glad.